# Static Variables in Apache module are initialized more then once?

Tags: c, apache, module, apache2, global-variables

I wrote a module for Apache HTTP server and discovered strange behaviour. I've assumed that static variables are initialized only once, but I wrote the code below and made two requests to Apache the output was:

```
test_handler: isInit=0
test_handler: isInit=1

test_handlere: isInit=0
test_handlere: isInit=1
```

The test code:

```
static int isInit = 0;

static int test_handler( request_rec *r ) {
    fprintf(stderr,"\n\natest_handler: isInit=%d", isInit );
    if( !isInit ) {
        isInit = 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr,"\natest_handler: isInit=%d", isInit );
    fflush(stderr);
    return DECLINED;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p) {
    fprintf(stdout,"register_hooks\n"); 
    ap_hook_translate_name(test_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);    
    fprintf(stdout,"register_hooks done\n");
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA test_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF, 
    NULL,                  /* create per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* create per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* table of config file commands       */
    register_hooks  /* register hooks                      */
};
```

The issue related to threads, since when I do 10 requests to Apache I see `isInit=1, isInit=1` in some cases and `isInit=0, isInit=1` in others.

My question is, **how I can define a variable, that will be accessible in `test_handler()` and will preserve its value between calls to the function?**

Answer (score 2):

I think, I found the problem. Apache Server for Linux creates several 'child' servers to serve paralel requests. Every virtual sever loads configuration, including module instantces, so if ApacheServer creates 8 child server proccesses, you 8 copies of isInit variable. You can configure Apache to create obly one server ( not recommended - performance ). Another way is to configure Apache Server to use other Multi-Proccess technologies, I read abot prefork and worker. According to Apache2 documentation on Windows the server uses Windows API, so you can migrate to Windows or write module that can work as several paralel instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can be related with a race condition that occurs when several threads runs simultaneously. The keyword `static` is only restricts the scope of the variable, so it's not a solution -- use something like `mutexes` for the purpose of the race condition exclusion. Speaking about keeping some variable between a function calls within a connection you'll need to store this variable in connection-related structures (see `request_rec->notes` or `request_rec->connection->notes` for example).

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'connection-related structures'. I've checked Apache API docs and there is no request_rec->connection->notes . 'request_rec->notes' is not for my case.

Comment: Look at the Apache2 API: http://www.rcbowen.com/httpd_api_docs/structrequest__rec.html

Comment: I see. It is different from official http://httpd.apache.org/dev/apidoc/apidoc_request_rec.html. I'll check what is written in my 'httpd.h'

Comment: Another comment. I don't think that it is race condition issue. the first test that I've made, is to do simple request twice from browser. I need approximately 0.5 second to do 'F5' in browser and request handling for is approximatlely 0.1 second or less. There is intersection between two requests, so there is no place for 'race' condition'.

Comment: You looked at v1.3 API's. I pointed to v2.0. I think that With the 1.3 version you'll need to manage structures like connection 'notes' by hand... As for the race condition, it seems that you are right there aren't races.

Comment: There is no docs for v2.0 API at apache server project site. Thank for the link to it.

Comment: Another test: after 8th I see <code>isInit=1, isInit=1</code> as supposed. In startip log I can see ' proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child..' line 8 time. I didn't worked with Apache Server before, so I didn't whether these two things are related.